# problem updating document Vuejs and Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating site for my store and learning Vue js at the same time. I'm having a problem with updating product. Data do not appear to be able to edit. I have seen many videos and I have not found the solution for a few days.
I'm using Vue js 3 and Firebase 9.

this is main.js

```
const dataBase = collection(db, "products");
```

and this products.js

```
<div v-if="toggle" to="body" class="modal">
          <input type="text" v-model="product.name" placeholder="Назва товару">              
          <input type="number" v-model="product.price" placeholder="Ціна">
          <input type="text" v-model="product.brand" placeholder="Бренд">
          <input type="text" v-model="product.category" placeholder="Категорія">           
          <button class="productbutton" @click="saveData" @click.stop="toggle = !toggle">Save</button>
          <button class="productbutton" @click="toggle = !toggle">Close</button>
</div>

<script>
    import { dataBase } from '../main';
    import { addDoc, deleteDoc, onSnapshot, updateDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    
    export default {
      name: "Products",
      setup() {
        return { toggle: ref(false) };
      },
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      data() {
        return {
          products: [],
          product: {
            name: '',
            price: '',
            brand: '',
            category: ''
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        saveData() {
          try {
            addDoc(dataBase, this.product).then((docRef) => {
              console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            })
          } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
          }
        },
        async deleteProduct(id) {
          if (confirm('Видалити ?')) {
            await deleteDoc(doc(dataBase, id));
          } else {
    
          }
        },
        async editProduct(id) {
          await updateDoc(doc(dataBase, { id }));
        }
      },
      created() {
        onSnapshot(dataBase, (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            this.products.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
          })
        });
      }
    };
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a problem only with saving/updating data, or can you not fetch them too?

Comment: when I press edit opens modal but the fields are empty

Comment: Can you check if you configured your connection with Firebase correctly? For example, try to print in the web console the collection id [__dataBase.id__](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference.md#collectionreference_class)